# Flash not showing in /dev but I see it in lsusb

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I have a USB flash drive. I formatted it some time ago, and an copy of my Bitcoin private keys were on it. I would like to recover it (it was formatted as Ext4, if I remember). After plugging the USB flash drive into my computer, no file like `sdb` appears in `/dev`, so GParted doesn’t see it. I can try this under Windows (or Ubuntu). Now, Im using an updated  install of Arch Linux running Xfce.

**UPDATE:** Windows detect it, and it seems that it has one partition with RAW filesystem, and one is empty space. I formatted one of them.

Comment: I wonder how did you format a USB flash drive partition in Windows leaving the other one intact. Windows doesn't natively support this option.

Comment: I formatted it in Linux using GParted

Answer (score 0):

If your question is to understand why it doesn't appears in `/dev` maybe you can check `$ dmesg` just after plugging in the key. It could give you some useful information.

You can paste the last lines of the output of `dmesg` on here, maybe it will help us to help you

Answer (score 0):

I'm idiot, now it's working. Probably just restart helped. (I updated my system too)